# Image Does Not Animate and is Stuck in one Frame

Tags: animation, libgdx, actor, scene2d

I'm having a problem in my code where the animation from another class does not animate and is stuck in one frame. The image moves across the screen in the right manner though. I know that the problem is somehow related to the UPDATE method of the animation. I have tried every possible solutions in my knowledge to find what causes the error and the solutions I found online were not quite helpful. Any help will be appreciated.

Here's my Code:

LevelOneScreen.java

```
public class LevelOneScreen implements Screen {

    private final MyGame app;
    WalkAnimate walkAnimate;
    private Stage stage;
    private Image levelOneImage;
    private Image holdStartImage;
    public Image walkRightImage;
    public Image walkLeftImage;
    public float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();




    public LevelOneScreen(final ThumbChase app){
        this.app = app;
        this.stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(app.screenWidth,app.screenHeight , app.camera));

    }
    @Override
    public void show() {

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        walkAnimate = new WalkAnimate();
        walkAnimate.update(deltaTime);


        levelOneBackground();
        holdStart();
        ninjaWalk();


    }



    public void holdStart(){
        Texture holdStartTexture = new Texture("HoldStart.png");
        holdStartImage = new Image(holdStartTexture);
        float holdStartImageW = holdStartImage.getWidth();
        float holdStartImageH = holdStartImage.getHeight();
        float holdStartImgWidth = app.screenWidth*0.8f;
        float holdStartImgHeight = holdStartImgWidth *(holdStartImageH/holdStartImageW);
        holdStartImage.isTouchable();
        holdStartImage.setSize(holdStartImgWidth,holdStartImgHeight);
        holdStartImage.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/2-holdStartImgWidth/2,stage.getHeight()/2-holdStartImgHeight/2);
        stage.addActor(holdStartImage);
        holdStartImage.addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
           /* public void touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
                holdStartImage.setVisible(false);
            };*/
           public void fling(InputEvent event, float velocityX, float velocityY, int button)  {
               holdStartImage.setVisible(false);
           }
            public void touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
                holdStartImage.setVisible(false);
            };
            public void touchDrag (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
                holdStartImage.setVisible(false);
            };

        });


        }


    public void levelOneBackground(){
        Texture levelOneTexture = new Texture("BGBlue Resize.png");
        levelOneImage = new Image(levelOneTexture);
        levelOneImage.setSize(app.screenWidth,app.screenHeight);
        levelOneImage.setPosition(0,0);
        stage.addActor(levelOneImage);
        /*levelOneImage.addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
            public void touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
                holdStartImage.setVisible(false);
            };
        });*/
    }
    public void ninjaWalk(){
        TextureRegion ninjaWalkRight = new TextureRegion(walkAnimate.getCurrentFrameRight());
        TextureRegion ninjaWalkLeft = new TextureRegion(walkAnimate.getCurrentFrameLeft());
        //Texture ninjaWalkRight = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        //Texture ninjaWalkLeft = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        walkRightImage = new Image(ninjaWalkRight);
        walkLeftImage = new Image(ninjaWalkLeft);
        float walkImageW = walkRightImage.getWidth();
        float walkImageH = walkRightImage.getHeight();
        float walkImageWidth = app.screenWidth*0.25f;
        float walkImageHeight = walkImageWidth*(walkImageH/walkImageW);
        walkRightImage.isTouchable();
        walkLeftImage.isTouchable();
        walkRightImage.setSize(walkImageWidth,walkImageHeight);
        walkLeftImage.setSize(walkImageWidth,walkImageHeight);
        walkRightImage.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/2-walkImageWidth/2,0);
        walkLeftImage.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/2-walkImageWidth/2,0);
        walkRightImage.addAction(moveBy(app.screenWidth*0.2f,0,1f));
        stage.addActor(walkRightImage);
        walkRightImage.addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
            public void pan(InputEvent event, float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
                holdStartImage.setVisible(true);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        //walkAnimate.update(deltaTime);
        update(delta);
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime){
        stage.act(deltaTime);

        stage.draw();
        app.batch.begin();

        app.batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();

    }
}
```

WalkAnimate.java

```
public class WalkAnimate {

        public MyGame app;
        public Stage stage;


        private Animation walkAnimationRight;
        private Animation walkAnimationLeft;
        private Texture walkSheetRight;
        private Texture walkSheetLeft;
        private TextureRegion[] walkFramesRight;
        private TextureRegion[] walkFramesLeft;
        private TextureRegion   currentFrameRight;
        private TextureRegion   currentFrameLeft;
        private float stateTime;
        private Rectangle bound; //used for positioning and collision detection
        private static final int  FRAME_COLS_WALK = 3;
        private static final int  FRAME_ROWS_WALK= 2;
        private float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        private float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        public float currentFrameWidth = (float)(screenHeight*0.15);
        public float currentFrameHeight = (float)(screenHeight*0.15);
        public float walkSheetWidth;
        public float walkSheetHeight;



        public WalkAnimate () {

            walkSheetRight = new Texture("ninjaWalkRight.png");
            walkSheetWidth = walkSheetRight.getWidth();
            walkSheetHeight = walkSheetRight.getWidth();
            TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheetRight, (int) walkSheetRight.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS_WALK, (int) walkSheetRight.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS_WALK);
            walkFramesRight = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS_WALK * FRAME_ROWS_WALK];
            int index = 0 ;
            for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS_WALK; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS_WALK; j++) {
                    walkFramesRight[index++] = tmp[i][j];
                }
            }
            walkAnimationRight = new Animation(0.044f, walkFramesRight);
            stateTime = 0f;


            walkSheetLeft = new Texture("ninjaWalkLeft.png");
            walkSheetWidth = walkSheetLeft.getWidth();
            walkSheetHeight = walkSheetLeft.getWidth();
            TextureRegion[][] tmp1 = TextureRegion.split(walkSheetLeft, (int) walkSheetRight.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS_WALK, (int)walkSheetLeft.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS_WALK);
            walkFramesLeft = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS_WALK * FRAME_ROWS_WALK];
            int index1 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS_WALK; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS_WALK; j++) {
                    walkFramesLeft[index1++] = tmp1 [i][j];
                }
            }
            walkAnimationLeft = new Animation(0.044f, walkFramesLeft);
            stateTime = 0f;

            currentFrameRight = walkAnimationRight.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
            currentFrameLeft = walkAnimationLeft.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);




        }


        public Rectangle getBound(){
            return bound;
        }

        public void update(float delta){
            stateTime += delta;



        }


        public TextureRegion getCurrentFrameRight(){
            return currentFrameRight;

        }
        public TextureRegion getCurrentFrameLeft(){
            return currentFrameLeft;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why is walkAnimate.update() in show()? I think you would want it to constantly update, so you should put it in render()

Comment: Can you take a look at my question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136318/how-to-refresh-dependencies-after-adding-freetype-extension-in-android-project

Comment: Guys can you visit my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971321/how-to-restart-screen-in-libgdx-using-init-methods

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will answer my question, I've tried using a separate stage for the animation and it works. I also used inputmultiplexor to set two stages both as inputprocessors. I know that this is not the best solution and I am open for more proper solutions. This is open for editing.

Comment: What actually is the answer? `Multiplexer` has nothing to do with your animation and most probably neither does `Stage`. I think your biggest issue is not knowing how to debug, you really should be able to tell exactly what is `null` when you get a `NullPointerEeception`. Debugging is one of the core skills you need when developing anything larger then 100 lines of code.

Comment: Yep I admit for a beginner that is the best solution I can provide, this answer is open for any edits or better solutions.

Comment: Can you take a look at my new posted question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/why-does-the-texture-from-assetmanager-displays-black-rectangles-only-libgdx

Comment: Can you take a look at my question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136318/how-to-refresh-dependencies-after-adding-freetype-extension-in-android-project

Comment: Guys can you visit my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971321/how-to-restart-screen-in-libgdx-using-init-methods

Answer (score 0):

Like the earlier comment by Eames. Just by glancing at your code, I can say that you should begin by moving

> walkAnimate.update(delta);

To the render section. The show section only runs once (when the class is started). Your walkAnimate.update(delta) should be running constantly to change the frame when is time. Otherwise it would only update once.

You can also do it the way I do it.

The class where you are going to use it. The 16 represents the number of images. The 1F means it is done in one second.

```
public void show() {
        texture = new Texture("item/coin_animation.png");
        animation = new Animation(new TextureRegion(texture), 16, 1f);
}


public void render(float delta) {
        animation.update(delta);
}
```

Animation Class

```
public Array<TextureRegion> frames;
private float maxFrameTime;
private float currentFrameTime;
private int frameCount;
private int frame;
private static TextureRegion textureRegion;

public Animation(TextureRegion region, int frameCount, float cycleTime){

    textureRegion = region;

    frames = new Array<TextureRegion>();
    int frameWidth = textureRegion.getRegionWidth() / frameCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++){
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(textureRegion, i * frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, textureRegion.getRegionHeight()));
    }


    this.frameCount = frameCount;
    maxFrameTime = cycleTime / frameCount;
    frame = 0;
}


public void update(float delta){
    currentFrameTime += delta;
    if (currentFrameTime > maxFrameTime){
        frame++;
        currentFrameTime = 0;
    }

    if (frame >= frameCount)
        frame = 0;
}


public TextureRegion getFrame(){
    return  frames.get(frame);
}

public void restart(){
    frame = 0;
    currentFrameTime = 0;
}
```

Comment: I have done that and it returns a NullPointerException.

Comment: Well I thought one couldn't comment until you reach 15 points, but can you post the whole error? I want to see what it says after the NullPointException.

Comment: Are you sure you have 
        walkAnimate = new WalkAnimate();

Comment: Are you sure you have walkAnimate = new WalkAnimate(); in Show()??

Comment: Here's what it says:
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.setRegion(TextureRegion.java:112)
                                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.<init>(TextureRegion.java:63)
                                                                                    at com.jpfalmazan.thumbchaseninja.GameScreens.LevelOneScreen.ninjaWalk(LevelOneScreen.java:113)
at com.jpfalmazan.thumbchaseninja.GameScreens.LevelOneScreen.show(LevelOneScreen.java:62)

Comment: The LevelOneScre‌​en.java:113 is at the TextureRegions and LevelOneScreen.ja‌​va:62 is at ninjaWalk() in show,

Comment: Yes I have walkAnimate = new WalkAnimate() in show right after Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage).

Comment: Sorry that is really not telling

Comment: Sorry that is really not telling me much

Comment: So it is actually not your animation class anymore. You would have to check ninjawalk(); and see what is wrong there. Also you might want to correct 
            walkSheetHeight = walkSheetLeft.getWidth();

Comment: No problem. I have also tried putting walkAnimate.update in the update method of levelonescreen and then calling the update method in render. It  still does not animate.

Comment: Well your animation class looks complicated. And if you want to really get the hang of libGDX then I recommend you to start doing things from the ground up. I suppose you learned to do the animation class from a tutorial. There are some things there that I honestly haven't yet covered on my own. I am 99% done with my first game for Android. And I am planning to release the beta today or tomorrow. My point is that I made a whole game. And I did not need to cover some of the things that you are planning on using. To me it seems you could make things easier for yourself.

Comment: I would recommend that you try building my animation class part by part so you can understand it. You could also use it to replace the one you have right now, I think you might benefit from it. As it just a select a texture, number of frames, and time thing. Right from the same class. When you don't want to draw an animation you just put an if statement in the draw section of your class;

Comment: like if (drawLeft){

Comment: batch.draw(animation.getFrame(), vector2.x, vector2.y);

Comment: and just reset it when you are done. animation.reset();

Comment: I get your point, I just thought it will be a lot easier if I use my characters as actors because  I can add actions to it especially moveBy/moveTo and the duration as well as changing the image after a given condition using setDrawable new SpriteDrawable.. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you read about libGDX as much as you can, then draw a map of the whole game. Menus, settings, and code implementation. Just plan everything out to get things to work the best way possible before you start coding. Do some research if you are unsure things will work.

Comment: I spent 8 months on my game. I made dozen of sprites, backgrounds, menus, sounds. A lot of them I did not end up in the game for optimization, time, game theme or whatever problem that came up. I wrote almost every class in a complete different way at least three times each. I have around 50 different classes, that I made for my game. If I could go back in time I would have planned everything out and the game could have been done in around 5 months. I started from 0 just like you. The game is called Car Journey if you want to check it out and see what I was able to accomplish in 8 months.

Comment: Guys can you visit my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971321/how-to-restart-screen-in-libgdx-using-init-methods